# How to relocate svn repository when using git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am using git-svn to access a subversion repository that the sys admin has just relocated to another machine.  If I were using the normal subversion client, I would just do `svn switch --relocate` to fix the problem, but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent operation using git-svn.  Can this be done?

I have checked that `svn switch --relocate` does work when using the normal svn client (i.e., the UUID's are the same for the old and new repositories so the switch is possible).

The reason that I want to "switch" instead of just re-cloning the repository is that the repository is large and I have a lot of untracked files in the existing working copy that I want to hold onto.  Alternatively, if there is a way to "clone" over the existing working copy, keeping the untracked files, that would work also.

Comment: OK, yes this is a duplicate of that question.  But I am running into a new problem that maybe wasn't seen before, something to do with finding remote branches when they are in non-traditional places:

$ git svn rebase
refs/remotes/abranch_0.1: '<new repo url>' not found in '<old repo url>/branches/abranch'

Comment: Ok, then that should be a new question.